# Caliburn Micro WinRT state handling

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, caliburn.micro

Is there any support for Suspend and resume available in WinRT version of Caiburn Micro? If yes is the answer, how i can implement Suspend/Resume functionality with this architecture. I don't believe a full fledged architecture like caliburn micro does't support state handling.

Also how i can persist navigation while deactivation, something like the navigation behavior of windows phone.

Please anyone help me to solve this issue

Comment: I am also interested in this. Have you found out how to save state in caliburn micro viewmodel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several pages of documentation on this - it's been a while since I've worked with caliburn.micro, so I'm not sure if these will completely answer your question, but here you go:

[Screens, Conductors and Composition](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/10/08/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-part-6a-screens-conductors-and-composition.aspx)

The gist of this is "Inherit from Screen". This will give you `OnActivate()` and `OnDeactivate()` methods to override, among others. You can use these for suspending and resuming your application.

Also, there's "Tombstoning" support for WP7 in caliburn.micro via `StorageHandler`s - maybe the corresponding classes are available for WinRT as well. Here's some documentation on those:

[Working with Windows Phone 7 v1.1](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Working%20with%20Windows%20Phone%207%20v1.1&referringTitle=Documentation)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, I think, OnActivate() and OnDeactivate() is not the ideal solution to handle "tombstone" in WinRT. These overrides will fire just once when the View becomes Active or destroyed, not everytime the View goes out of focus and comes back.

I have not come across Suspend/Resume feature in Caliburn.Micro WinRT yet.

But this can be easily achieved with the .NET infrastructure instead. Follow this [msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/06/17/suspend-and-resume-in-winrt.aspx) link for full details.

In short,

to handle Navigation away and return (App minimized and resumed) use below event in ViewModels:

```
Window.Current.VisibilityChanged += OnVisibilityChanged;
```

to handle Suspend/Resume override OnSuspending and OnResuming in App class.